# Capistrano can't deploy from non-master branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm using Capistrano (3.7.1) to deploy my Rails 5 application to a VPS. I have 2 major branches I'm using in git: `master`, for stable, production-ready code, and `develop`, for WIP code. I wanted to deploy the `develop` branch to a staging server, but it doesn't seem to be working.

**In `deploy.rb`:**

```
# This is the failing task
task :check_revision do
  on roles(:app) do
    unless 'git rev-parse HEAD' == "git rev-parse origin/#{fetch(:branch)}"
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/#{fetch(:branch)}"
      puts 'Run `git push` to sync changes.'
      exit
    end
  end
end
```

**In `production.rb`:**

```
set :branch, 'master'
```

**In `staging.rb`:**

```
set :branch, 'develop'
```

Every time I try to deploy, it's failing, as follows:

```
$ cap staging deploy
... initial steps, skipped over ...
WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/develop
Run `git push` to sync changes.
```

But this is clearly not the case, as I'm getting:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
38e4a194271780246391cf3977352cb7cb13fc86
$ git rev-parse origin/develop
38e4a194271780246391cf3977352cb7cb13fc86
```

which are clearly the same.

What's going on?

Comment: Change the line to this and try: `unless \`git rev-parse HEAD\` == \`git rev-parse origin/#{fetch(:branch)}\``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing the commands which should run on the shell in single quotes which ruby is treating as `String`:

```
unless 'git rev-parse HEAD' == 'git rev-parse origin/#{fetch(:branch)}'
```

instead of this:

```
unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/#{fetch(:branch)}`
```

also you can use:

```
unless %x{git rev-parse HEAD} == %x{git rev-parse origin/#{fetch(:branch)}}
```

`%x` also returns the standard output of running cmd in a subshell.

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks to execute `git` commands in your script:

```
# This is the failing task
task :check_revision do
  on roles(:app) do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/#{fetch(:branch)}`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/#{fetch(:branch)}"
      puts 'Run `git push` to sync changes.'
      exit
    end
  end
end
```